# Unable to connect SSH on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

My SSH and FTP connection suddenly stopped working. I am unable to connect with my ec2 instance running ubuntu using SSH and FTP, here is the setting of my instance.

Security group setting:

Inbound:

```
`SSH    TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0`
```

Outbound:

```
`All traffic    All All 0.0.0.0/0`
```

Connecting using the command:

```
`ssh -v -i "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com`
```

and getting below message:

`OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1e  17 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file eotraceeu.pem type -1
debug1: identity file eotraceeu.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22`

Is there anything else I need to set up to be able to connect to the EC2 instance?

Comment: did you login to aws console using a browser and confirm the instance is running ?

Comment: When I connect using the browser using EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection) with ubuntu user get below error. `There was a problem setting up the instance connection
`The remote desktop server encountered an error and has closed the connection. Please try again or contact your system administrator.`

Comment: `ssh -vv ` will boost the verbosity of error messages to help you see the issue  ... using a browser do not try to login just go to EC2 page in aws console site and view instances to confirm its State is running ...  aws console -> EC2 -> Running instances ... here it lists all instances in chosen region ... there confirm the instance State is running

Comment: I have checked instance is in running state and reboot it also. here is ssh -vv details. `ssh -vv -i "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: `OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1e  17 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com [15.188.243.230] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file eotraceeu.pem type -1
debug1: identity file eotraceeu.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2`

Comment: `debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22`

Comment: you said ssh was working before ... what changed ?  ... I would just destroy that instance and spin up a new one

Comment: Yes, you right to spin another instance, but the issue is I am running a website on that instance. Is there any way to move content and configuration and hook up with a new instance?

Comment: I didn't changed anything but same account and the key was used in multiple users in putty and filezilla.

Comment: code + config to launch a site should be in a github.com or git elsewhere or some other content version control system so source code never actually lives on any one machine ... in aws when creating a new instance there is a setting to optionally save the volume(s) when instance is terminated, if you set that to save volume you can spin up a new instance and mount that volume .. aws S3 is an easy way to save dirs as volumes which persist ... goto browser aws console -> EC2 -> Elastic Block Store on left -> Volumes -> and take a snapshot of each volume then mount it on new instance, no promises